# How make subproject(cakephp) in cakephp project

Tags: cakephp

I have a project for example prodect_1. Now i have another project example porject_2. My project_1 is on root in my domain. I want to run my second project in project_1, like www.abc.com/project_1/project_2.

Please help me if anyone have any idea for this task.

Comment: just copy the app folder of `project_1` and rename it `project_2`

Comment: but where paste this copied folder, my project_1 is in cakephp2, and project_2 is in cakephp3

Comment: just copy and paste there only, i.e. cakephp2